# numpy.hstack() not working in a jitted function

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, jit, numba

The numba website https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/numpysupported.html says it supports numpy.hstack(). But in practice, it simply doesn't.

```
from numba import njit
import numpy as np

@njit
def func(data):return np.hstack((np.nan, data))

myarray = np.arange(100)*0.1
X =func(myarray)
```

So what am I missing here? The function seems trivial enough but it just doesn't work. The error message is the following:

```
TypingError: Invalid use of Function(<function hstack at 0x0000022D26441BF8>) with argument(s) of type(s): ((float64, array(float64, 1d, C)))
 * parameterized
In definition 0:
    TypeError: np.hstack(): expecting a non-empty tuple of arrays, got (float64, array(float64, 1d, C))
    raised from C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\typing\npydecl.py:806
In definition 1:
    TypeError: np.hstack(): expecting a non-empty tuple of arrays, got (float64, array(float64, 1d, C))
    raised from C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\typing\npydecl.py:806
This error is usually caused by passing an argument of a type that is unsupported by the named function.
[1] During: resolving callee type: Function(<function hstack at 0x0000022D26441BF8>)
[2] During: typing of call at C:/Users/User/Desktop/all python file/4.2.1/np_stack_test_njit.py (13)
```

Comment: `np.hstack((np.array([np.nan]), data))` works for me, but that doesn't explain the inconsistency with `numba` vs regular NumPy.

Comment: yeah that's what I have noticed too. the function with np.hstack() works nicely until then point I have introduced @njit, then it just doesn't work.

Comment: `nan` isn't an array. `np.hstack` is ok with that, but `numba's` version seems to be pickier about that.  Compiled stuff often is.

Comment: The Python version first runs each element through `atleast_1d`.  Flexibility like that comes at a processing cost, which `numba` may be trying to avoid.